# upgraded to fuerte, how do i install stacks?

Tags: ros, rosinstall, build-from-source

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I upgraded from electric to fuerte today (ubuntu 10.04), and noticed a few big changes. The biggest is that I can no longer find the source for a number of packages I used for validation/test, such as roscpp and roscpp_tutorials.  I see the binary versions in the fuerte/share directory, but cannot seem to find a way to get the source itself.  Reading the installation instructions, I think I need to install rosinstall package, however both easy_install and pip fail.

any ideas? (i know i can pull the source directly from the repositories, but would like to do it in a more integrated/"ros" way)

pip output:
[rdean@RCTA-HSS81P1 ~]$ sudo pip install -U rosinstall vcstools rosdep
Unknown option: u
Unknown or unsupported command 'install'

Thanks,
Bob

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/33448/upgraded-to-fuerte,-how-do-i-install-stacks?/) by [Bob Dean](https://answers.ros.org/users/2328/bob-dean/) on ROS Answers with karma: 61 on 2012-05-07

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

All packages that use catkin provide a real install target in their CMakeLists.txt. One side effect of that is that C++ programs don't install their source code, i.e. the source code for roscpp, tf, etc. is no longer installed when using the Debian packages.

I think using rosinstall/rosws only makes sense if you want to build these packages from source. In that case follow the instructions [here](http://www.ros.org/wiki/fuerte/Installation/Ubuntu/Source).

If you just want to find the source code for a stack, you can use roslocate and check out the code yourself (preferably to a location that is not in your ROS_PACKAGE_PATH to prevent conflicts). Example:

```
$ roslocate info roscpp
- svn:
    local-name: roscpp
    uri: https://code.ros.org/svn/ros/stacks/ros_comm/tags/electric/clients/cpp/roscpp
```

Unfortunately, the URI is pointing to electric, but by just replacing electric with fuerte, you get the right repository URI.

Btw. I'm not sure why your pip command throws an error but try leaving out the -U option.

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2012-05-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3